# In CSS, can I use the same name for a CSS class and a CSS animation?

Tags: html, css

Or are there risks of conflicts ?

Example code provided

```html
<style>
.wobble {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background: #777;
}
.wobble:hover {
  animation-name: wobble;
  animation-duration: 0.8s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  transform-origin: 50% 100%;

  -webkit-animation-name: wobble;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.8s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
}

@keyframes wobble {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
  15% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -5deg);
    transform: translate3d(-25%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -5deg);
  }
  30% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(20%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 3deg);
    transform: translate3d(20%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 3deg);
  }
  45% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-15%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
    transform: translate3d(-15%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -3deg);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(10%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 2deg);
    transform: translate3d(10%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 2deg);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-5%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -1deg);
    transform: translate3d(-5%, 0, 0) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -1deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}
</style>


<div class="wobble">Wobble</div>
```

Comment: There is no risk of conflict. This is often how people remember what a CSS class does. The class name is referenced for DOM elements, and the animation name is referenced by a CSS property.

Comment: What do you mean by "risk of conflicts"? It's unclear what information you are looking for since the answer to your question is self-evident from just running this code and looking at the outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never gotten an error for having a `class` and a `@keyframes` named the same thing. It is the same idea of having an `id` and a `class` with the same name on a HTML tag.

There should be no conflicts, unless there was a similar situation with JavaScript (functions, variable names, etc.).